# How to count how many people read an article

Tags: php

I am programming a Blog. I am interested how to add a counter to the side to see how many people read the different articles.

I understood that if you have a Website counter, than you would normally save the IP and the Date in the database so you only count the person once.

But how would I make sure that a person reading a specific article is only counted once for that article?

The database would turn very big if I would save each Visitor IP for each Article. It came now into my mind to maybe create a Session for every Visitor. Within this Session I save each ArticleID the Person read. So before I update the counter in the database, I check if it already exists in Session - if not increment counter and save in Session otherwise dont.

Is this the right approach or is there another way to do it?

Comment: what is he entered the article and didn't read it. how will you count it? :)

Comment: OK, Ok, its never 100%. What is if he read it but did not understand... So if you want you can call it how many viewed it, opened it or whatever. Its about the principle and to give an idea how many actually clied on an article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set a cookie on the user's browser and send it to the server.  If the cookie is new, it's a new user reading the article for the first time.

Comment: And if a user only visits one page the cookie never gets send back.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answers. I don't want to count on refresh, this always looks pretty bad when people realise it, but what I am not sure now is why would I use a Cookie? A Cookie would be saved on the Users PC, why would I not just use a Session ?

Comment: sessions expire when people leave the webpage. the other solution is to store this in a database based on the IP-adress, but this does not completely solve the problem. several people could be using the same IP-adress.

Comment: @OptimusCrime Exactly and what to do in that case, is there a way to get a unique id when several people are using the same ip ? Are we then supposed to refer to the browser ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which data you want to save. You can save:

1. Number of hits (count all people/bots/... who opened the pages), this makes fake impression of readers, because doing a refresh will count me twice.
2. Number of unique visitors,  create a session for the user. and increment the counter only once in the session. This can be improved by setting permanent cookie, but looks like overkill for me. and by the way, I can open the article and don't read it!
3. Number of people interact with the article. You can put some javascript capture (mouse scrolling, clicks on article text, ...) , split text into parts with "read more" ... etc.

If I were you, I will name it "number of views", and use solution 2. And combine this with google analytics (or similar solution) to know more details about visitors.

Answer (score 3):

Google analytics is better way

But if you want to do it by programming then follow the steps.

i) In your table from the data of particular article comes just add one column no_of_view or                        whatever you want to give..

ii) In the starting of page write down the code of php for ::

```
     from the url you can get the id of current article.
     then from select query get the value of column no_of_view for particular ID (article)
     then fire a query for update that record for no_of_view column with +1

   If you want to get that more accurate then add ipaddress column and date also....
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use Google Analitycs API for such tasks. It' hard to implement for the first time - but once made it will help you on any project.

You can read here - http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html

Comment: I have used Google Analytics before, but I had to log into my Account and than see the Sts about the site. What I now want to reach is display the Count on the Page itself for everybody to read. Or are you saying this is possible with G. A?

Comment: @phgrey talks about Google analytics API, not normal analytics.

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought that its something else. But think its probably to complicated to get into it...

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can execute an ajax function, when user click on article to update column in database table field name 'number_of_click' as per article id and other relevant reference

and show it by simple query 'SELECT no_of_click FROM article WHERE id='{$individual_article_id} ....'';